decomposition of direct sum of finite dimension vector space
I want to prove this proposition:
Let $V= \oplus_{i=0,1...n}V_i$ where $V_i$ are finite dimension vector spaces over a field $\Bbb F$, and $a_i$ are $\Bbb F$ linear map between $V_i$ and $V_i+1$. Define a linear map $t:V\to V$ by sending $ t(v_0,,,v_n)=(0, a_0(v_0), \ldots, a_{n-1}(v_{n-1})) $ and by structure theorem of finitely generate module over pid, $V=F \oplus T$, where $F$ is the free part, and T is the torsion part.

Proposition: Prove that F is of the form $t^i \Bbb F[t]$ for some $i>0$, and $T$ is $t^h(\Bbb F[t]/(t^j))$ for some $h<j$.

Here is my approach:
Since $V$ is of finite dimension, say $m$ dimension, define a surjective map $k:\Bbb F[t]^m \to V$ by sending standard basis $(e_{i})_{i=1,,,m}$ of $\Bbb F[t]^m$ to an arbitrary chosen basis of $V$. Then we get $V$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F[t]^m / \textrm{ker}(k)$. Also I know that there exist another basis {$j_i$} of $\Bbb F[t]^m$ such that there exist $p_1,\ldots,p_l \in \Bbb F[t]$ such that $({p_ij_i})_{i=0, \ldots ,l}$ $l \le m$ is a basis of ker($k$).
As a result, $V$ is isomorphic to  $(\Bbb F[t]j_1 / \Bbb F[t]j_1p_1)$..$\oplus  \Bbb F[t]j_{l+1} \oplus \Bbb F[t]j_{l+2} \oplus \Bbb F[t]j_m$.
Now,
finally, I am stucking that how can we choose such $j_i,p_i \in\Bbb F[t]$
, such that they are of the form $t^i$ for some i.
Could someone help me?
Any advise or relative soloution is appreciate, thanks in advanced.

sorry, I don't understand why you associate to this hint?

yes, I do do the calculate. For me, I just straight forward check. In order words, I only find$ t^n(v_1,,,,v_n)=(0,0,0,0,..(a_n)(a_n-1)..(a_1)(v_1)...)$, do you mean I need to use matrix?

I think $t^n(V)={0}$ so that the minimal polynomial and so all the elementary divisors are powers of $X$.

well, I was exactly confused the next step before, I know that $t^n(V)={0}$ implies that $p_i$ are all of the form $x^b$ for some $b$, but in many book, they always use isomorphism ,so I can't see how can  Ichoose such $j_i$ for all $i $ in the form $x^d$ for some $d$

Also, I also confused that how $t^n$ acts on $\Bbb F[t]j_m$

NOT THE SAME,it is just notation.sorry for that natation

I have deleted my earliest comments. I can't see that what is asserted is true in even an easy special case: $n=1$, $\dim V_0=\dim V_1=1$, $a_0(u)=0$. By the usual theorem we'll get $V\simeq \mathbb{F}[X]/\langle X\rangle\oplus \mathbb{F}[X]/\langle X\rangle$ which I can't make isomorphic to any $t^h(\mathbb{F}[t]/\langle t^j\rangle)$.

Well, I have got the answer after using black board, I believe that it is true. However, it need to lots of correct on latex, I will post my answer after a truelylong time.

I do not think that this can be true in general.
(A) We have that $t^n(V)=\{0\}$ by an easy calculation, so that $\mathbb{F}[t]$ is of dimension (as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space) at most $n$, being spanned by $1,t,\dots,t^{n-1}$.
Suppose the proposition is true.
(B) $t^{i}\mathbb{F}[t]$ is spanned as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space by $t^i,\dots, t^{n-1}$. Hence $F$ has dimension (as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space) at most $n$.
(C) $\mathbb{F}[t]/\langle t^j\rangle$ is spanned as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space by $1+\langle t^j\rangle,\dots,t^{n-1}+\langle t^j\rangle$, and so $t^h\left(\mathbb{F}[t]/\langle t^j\rangle\right)$ is spanned by $t^h+\langle t^j\rangle,\dots,t^{n-1}+\langle t^j\rangle$. Hence $T$ has dimension (as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space) at most $n$.
(D) Hence $\dim V=\dim F +\dim T\leqslant 2n$.
(E) But suppose that each $V_i$ has dimension $3$ and all the $a_r$ are zero maps. We have that $\dim V=\dim V_0+\dots\dim V_n=3(n+1)>2n$.
[If I have misunderstood something please tell me and I'll delete this.]
